# Proving convergence for a two-dimensional integral that cannot be solved

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I want to prove the convergence of a two-dimensional integral, for which I do not have a solution but I know from numerics that it is convergent:
$$\int^{2 \pi}_0  d \theta   \int^{A}_{ 0   } d \kappa  \frac{  \kappa  ( \kappa \sin (\theta )     - 1 )  }{   ( B \kappa^{ 2}  \cos^2  (\theta )    +    \kappa^2 \sin^2  (\theta )     - 2        \kappa \sin  (\theta )      +     1       )^{3/2}  }    .$$ Here $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary positive coefficients. What I can find online is that you can prove either by solving it (which seems impossible) or by using a function that you can solve which you know is larger than the integrand everywhere in the domain you are integrating over. For the latter, what I could do is use that the integrand is always smaller than the following one:
$\int^{2 \pi}_0  d \theta   \int^{A}_{ 0   } d \kappa  \frac{  \kappa   }{   (     \kappa \sin  (\theta )     - 1     )^2  }    $, but it seems like this integral does not have a nice analytic solution either.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full solution, but it should give you a good start.

We only need to be concerned with the points $$B \kappa^2\cos^2\theta+\kappa^2 \sin^2\theta- 2\kappa \sin\theta+1$$ vanishes, since the integrand is continuous elsewhere.

$$f(\kappa,\theta)=B \kappa^2\cos^2\theta+\kappa^2 \sin^2\theta- 2\kappa \sin\theta+1=(\sqrt B\kappa\cos\theta)^2+(\kappa\sin\theta-1)^2$$ so that $f(\kappa,\theta)=0$ if and only if $$(\kappa,\theta)=\left(1,\frac\pi2\right)$$

If $A<1$, the integrand is continuous on the region of integration, hence integrable.  If $A\geq1$ we note that the numerator of the integrand vanishes when the denominator does, so it is still possible that the function can be defined to be continuous at that point.

In any event, the question of integrability can be resolved by determining the behavior of $f$ in a neighborhood of $\left(1,\frac\pi2\right)$.  Note that it is possible that the function be integrable even if it turns out to be discontinuous.

**EDIT**

When $\theta=\frac\pi2$ the integrand becomes $\frac\kappa{(1-\kappa)^2}$, so one can show that the function is absolutely integrable near $\left(1,\frac\pi2\right)$, hence integrable.